# How can I completely disable cron so that it won't run even if the cron URL is hit or cron is ran manually?

Tags: 7, cron

When working on a dev site I'd like to put in a safeguard to make sure cron cannot run, even if triggered manually. Is there a way to do this in Drupal 7?

Comment: What are you trying to prevent cron?

Comment: Doesn't look like there's a clean way to do it - the cron run itself is wrapped up in `drupal_cron_run()`, regardless of the entry point, and that function doesn't offer a way to cancel. Maybe you could look at it from the other side, and instead try to hook into the specific functions you don't want to run on cron locally

Comment: @Clive, agreed, if there's no hook or other way to disable cron completely then I'll just disable or prevent on the specific modules that I want to keep from running accidently.